# Save win user name by SQL server trigger

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection-string, windows-authentication

There is a local FOX app connected to SQL Server database. There is a trigger in the database which saves changes to the db table like:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.UpdateContract
 SELECT 'OLD' RecordType,USER,SYSTEM_USER,@Time, (...)
```

I am developing the same app by .NET (C#) and don't know how to use the same trigger to save the name of user who is logged into my .NET app (or windows user). 
I can use static cs like

```
 SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Server=servername;Database=dbname;User Id=dbuser;Password=Pass;");
```

(but, sure, the trigger save this user name and not app user name )
Or this cs:

```
 SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername; Initial Catalog=dbname; Integrated Security=SSPI;");
```

(but in this case the trigger uses the server machine name)

Comment: Can you pass the app user name into that INSERT?

Comment: The SSPI should return a user in the format `Domain\User`.  Create SQL logins that match you apps logins.

Comment: Danyu, You mean to pass app logged user name into sql query, than edit trigger and use this passed name? Hmhm, it could work... For delete trigger it could be a little more difficult..

Comment: Alex, yes I know. But it's a little expensive for administration. But maybe this will be my only option..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SYSTEM_USER function with DEFAULT constraints in the CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements. You can also use it as any standard function.

If the user name and login name are different, SYSTEM_USER returns the login name.

If the current user is logged in to SQL Server by using Windows Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the Windows login identification name in the form: DOMAIN\user_login_name. However, if the current user is logged in to SQL Server by using SQL Server Authentication, SYSTEM_USER returns the SQL Server login identification name, such as WillisJo for a user logged in as WillisJo.

**SYSTEM_USER returns the name of the currently executing context. If the EXECUTE AS statement has been used to switch context, SYSTEM_USER returns the name of the impersonated context.**

There's a chance that your "non-C# version" is impersonating the context. You can apply this connection after you've connected to server:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'YourWindowsUsername';
```

that should switch the context. I am not sure if that's the correct approach, you might want to add new field to trigger: **CURRENT_USER**, this might be something you need.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)